# Undefined symbol in a Hackage package `double-conversion`

Tags: gcc, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to build the `double-conversion` package from Hackage. It builds OK but ghci can't load it. The complaint is:

```
Loading package double-conversion-0.2.0.0 ... linking ... <interactive>: 
/home/me/.cabal/lib/double-conversion-0.2.0.0/ghc-7.0.4/HSdouble-conversion-0.2.0.0.o: 
unknown symbol `_ZNK17double_conversion6Double5valueEv'
```

The `nm` output shows that the symbol is **weak**:

```
nm /home/me/.cabal/lib/double-conversion-0.2.0.0/ghc-7.0.4/HSdouble-conversion-0.2.0.0.o \
    | grep _ZNK17double_conversion6Double5valueEv
00000000 W _ZNK17double_conversion6Double5valueEv
```

This is the only weak symbol in the file, and indeed, as far as I can tell, in the entire world of GHC-compiled packages.

The problematic function is apparently a FFI one, written in C++ and defined inline in `double-conversion/src/double.h`. It's not the only inline function there, but only this one gets labelled weak.

As a stopgap measure I have moved the function out-of-line, and the package now loads. But there's obviously some problem somewhere in there. Why this function is weak? Why other functions are not? Should ghc complain at weak symbols? Should I file a bug, and if so, who should get it (double-conversion, gcc, ghc, someone else?)

System data: Gentoo Linux, gcc-4.4.5, ghc-7.0.4, cabal-1.10.2.0.

Comment: What error do you get if you try to install `text-format`? Maybe Yesod tries to use double-conversion from Template Haskell?

Comment: Have you tried using the overlay?

Comment: @monadic: I am actually using the overlay, only after it failed I tried local `cabal install`. The error message is the same. @Mikhail Glushenkov: I actually can install `text-format`, but not `yesod`. The error message is the same.

Comment: I experienced the same issue with ghc-7.6.3 on Ubuntu-10.04 when I was trying to build package which uses double-conversion with cabal. Ghci failed too. To my surprise, simple ghc --make worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This ticket on GHC Trac looks relevant: [Can't use ghci with a library linked against libstdc++](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5289).</strike> This looks like a Gentoo (or possibly GCC 4.4)-specific problem - the `.o` file in question doesn't contain any weak symbols on my system (I tested on Ubuntu Natty with GCC 4.5.2 & GHC 7.0.3/7.0.4). I suggest you file a ticket on GHC Trac. Incidentally, I can reproduce #5289.

Comment: This is not just GHCi. Packages that depend on `double-conversion` do not install either (ultimately I'm trying to build `yesod`). The error message is also different.

Comment: Interesting! `cabal install text-conversion` works for me, so this is probably a Gentoo-specific problem. `nm` doesn't show any weak symbols in `HSdouble-conversion-0.2.0.0.o` on my system.

Comment: which version of ghc and gcc do you use?

Comment: After fixing the weak symbol issue, I'm aso getting the floating point exception in GHCi, as in #5289. So I guess the two are not related. I'll try to build with another gcc.

Comment: Tried it with gcc-4.6.0 and indeed there are no weak symbols. Anyway I think ghc should be able to handle weak symbols (they appear in e.g. C++ code that uses templates all the time).

Comment: How did you fix the weak symbols problem? I'm on Gentoo too, and have GCC 4.5 but that doesn't seem to have solved anything...

Comment: @ocharles: Sorry, didn't see your question. AFAIR I un-inlined the offending function in the source (that is, moved the implementation out of the header to the .C file).