# GHC: double-conversion-0.2.0.1 unknown symbol

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to use the latest release of EclipseFP.  Upon start, the scion-browser setup initializes, with everything going well until trying to install scion-browser-0.1.  I get the following error in my Eclipse console:

```
...
Loading package double-conversion-0.2.0.1 ... linking ... ghc: /home/dpm/.cabal/lib/double-conversion-0.2.0.1/ghc-7.0.3/HSdouble-conversion-0.2.0.1.o: unknown symbol `_ZNK17double_conversion6Double5valueEv'
ghc: unable to load package `double-conversion-0.2.0.1'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
scion-browser-0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Apparently, ghc-pkg seems to think everything is OK with this package (ghc-pkg check prints nothing).  Reinstalling double-conversion through cabal also changes nothing.  Anybody any idea what's going on?  I'm on Ubuntu 9.10 Linux, GHC 7.0.3 from the Haskell-Platform.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634373/undefined-symbol-in-a-hackage-package-double-conversion

Comment: @n.m.  Thanks, I didn't see that.

Comment: @n.m how did that question duplicate with this one?

Comment: @Sawyer: It looks like OP has undefined symbol `_ZNK17double_conversion6Double5valueEv` in `HSdouble-conversion-0.2.0.*.o`, exactly like I have. I conclude the two cases are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated [here](http://eclipsefp.github.com/faq.html)  :
close your eclipse and run this in your terminal:

```
cabal install blaze-textual --user -fnative --reinstall
cabal install aeson --user --reinstall
```

then, restart your eclipse.

Comment: Looks like it's a solution for a different problem